# SQL statement error for a sum with two conditions in Where clause

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

OK so I am using MVS 2015 to right a database using windows Forms and C#
This is what I coded

```
internal static decimal getExpenseSum(int parsedProjectID, string type)
    {
        decimal value = decimal.Zero;
        string query = "SELECT sum(TotalReceiptAmount) " +
                        "FROM Expense WHERE ProjectID = " + 
                        parsedProjectID + " AND Type = " + type;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        conn.Open();
        value = Convert.ToDecimal(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        conn.Close();
        return value;
    }
```

And I am getting a exception stating that the column name 'Parts' is not a valid column name. when "Parts" is the type string sent to the function.

Comment: I don't see any 'Parts' in the code you provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`type` is `varchar/string` type, surround it with quotes:

```
string query = "SELECT sum(TotalReceiptAmount) " +
                    "FROM Expense WHERE ProjectID = " + 
                    parsedProjectID + " AND Type = '" + type + "'";
                                                   ^____________^
```

For better readability do this for your `varchar/string` types:

```
type = "'" + type + "'";
string query = "SELECT sum(TotalReceiptAmount) " +
                    "FROM Expense WHERE ProjectID = " + 
                    parsedProjectID + " AND Type = " + type ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote your `type` parameter, otherwise it will be interpreted as a column name instead of a value:

```
string query = "SELECT SUM(TotalReceiptAmount) " +
               "FROM Expense WHERE ProjectID = " + 
               parsedProjectID + " AND Type = '" + type + "'";

                                              ^            ^
```

Better yet is to use [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) to

1. handle parameter types automatically;
2. safeguard your code against [sql injections](https://xkcd.com/327/);
3. optimize query execution.

Answer (score 0):

```
It seems like the string that you send to function - 'Parts' should be in quotes  when you compare for e.g. the resulting query from your code should  be :
SELECT sum(TotalReceiptAmount) FROM Expense WHERE ProjectID =                        parsedProjectID AND Type = 'Parts';
```

Answer (score 0):

New error Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

using

```
internal static decimal getExpenseSum(int parsedProjectID, string type)
    {
        decimal value = decimal.Zero;
        type = "'" + type + "'";
        string query = "SELECT sum(TotalReceiptAmount) " +
                        "FROM Expense WHERE ProjectID = " + 
                        parsedProjectID + " AND Type = " + type;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        conn.Open();
        value = Convert.ToDecimal(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        conn.Close();
        return value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK so that worked but I am doing it three times for ""Parts"" ""Tools"" and """other"" and of course Ive just only entered one for parts and then the form goes back to the project form and tries to do theese sums and there is nulls for Tools and Other. so Ill have to do a try catch.....
 but thank you all for the solve....
That is the meat of my project if you will workflow add customer....
Now on to adding projects to existing customers and then reports. YEAH and once again thank you